# Why was Jason chosen over his mother to be the villain?

Tags: production, friday-the-13th

In the first *Friday the 13th* movie, we saw that Jason's mother was the real villain. So what led the production house to switch to Jason rather than choosing his mother (or maybe choosing both of them) as a villain?

Comment: Maybe the mother being killed by decapitation in the first film had something to do with her not returning?

Comment: @MeatTrademark Lies and blasphemy! ...but yeah, that'd be my bet too

Comment: @MeatTrademark When has being killed ever stopped a horror villain from returning?!

Comment: Friday the 13th!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Jason Voorhees and his mother Pamela Voorhees are both portrayed as villains in the first movie.  Mrs. Vorhees as the actual villain, revealed at the end of the movie to be the person who commits the actual murders.  Jason appears at the end in a dream like sequence seen through the eyes of Alice, the lone survivor.

Jason was brought back in the sequel at the suggestion of one of the movies producers for the original [film](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080761/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv).

> The filmmakers never intended to make this the launching pad for the
>   series that followed. According to Victor Miller, Jason was only meant
>   as a plot device and not intended to continue on his mother's grisly
>   work.

The sequel actually shows Jason as a teenager/young adult for the first part of the film. Of course, Jason is seen five years later as a grown adult when he shows up to camp Crystal Lake to go on a murder spree to "guard" Camp Crystal Lake... and to avenge his mother's death.

Jason was actually never supposed to be in the films.  He was only in the last scene in the original as a [joke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friday_the_13th_(franchise)).

> Initial ideas for a sequel involved the Friday the 13th title being
>   used for a series of discontinuous films, released once a year, and
>   each would be a separate "scary movie" of its own right. Phil
>   Scuderi—a co‑owner of Esquire Theaters with Steve Minasian and Bob
>   Barsamian and a producer of the original film—insisted that the sequel
>   must have Jason Voorhees, Pamela's son, even though his appearance at
>   the end of the original film was only meant to be a joke. Steve Miner,
>   associate producer of the first film, believed in the idea, and he
>   ultimately directed the first two sequels after Cunningham opted not
>   to return to the director's chair.

Comment: I remember an article in Fangoria where someone involved (Miner, maybe?) suggested that their plan was to do one every year until 1993 which would be *Friday the 13th Part 13.* When nothing happened in 1983, and the year after that saw the so-called *Final Chapter* I don't remembering hearing any mention of the grand 13 part plan... That could have been **awfully** wonderful.

Comment: No, before that. When they were working on part 2 and planning part 3 they wanted to do one every year until Part13. They got sidetracked, lost some money or investors or something, and skipped a year. THEN they did Part IV, giving up on the 1 a year for 13 years plan. Trust me, I remember them all, acutely. I'm a horror geek who wanted to see one a year. I daydreamed about the series and part 13... I grew up in the 70's and 80's also and saw these flicks in the theater. Hell, in '84 after Nightmare, I tried to start a fanzine called The Elm Street Journal.

Comment: Crispin was in Part IV with Corey. I'm a big Crispy fan, even got a signed copy of his book Oak Mot and saw him live with *What Is it?* in 2006. I've seen sooo many horror flicks on the big screen. Loved Night of the Comet, One Dark Night, and April Fools Day. All under-rated classics, IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_Voorhees) explains it:

> Many ideas were suggested for the sequel to Friday the 13th, including making the title part of a serialized franchise, where each succeeding film would be its own story and not related to any previous film under the Friday the 13th moniker. It was Phil Scuderi, one of the producers for the original film, which suggested bringing Jason back for the sequel. The director Steve Miner felt it was the obvious direction to take the series, as he felt the audience wanted to know more about the child who attacked Alice in the lake. Miner decided to pretend as if Alice did not see the "real Jason" in her dream, and Jason had survived his drowning as a boy and had grown up.